# in pca, why maximum variance means minimum information loss

Tags: pca

can you please explain in principal component analysis (PCA), why maximum variance means minimum information loss?

Comment: It doesn't except for certain purposes, with information measured in certain ways.  (A standard counterexample is principal components regression, where the *relevant* information might, in the extreme, all reside in the component with *least* variance.) You therefore might want to provide a little more context for your question.

Comment: do you know why we want to maximize variance when we are computing the PCA? Is maximizing variance the same as retaining as much information as possible? thanks